# How do I access a specific argument without knowing it's type [variable arguments] in C?

Tags: c, arguments, type-conversion

Okay, so I am writing a log service that writes some data to some file (let's say the file's name is **log**).

The type of data that I want to write varies, it might be int or string or something else.

So far this is how my function looks:

```
void write_log(FILE * fp, char * event, ...)
{
    va_list list;
    va_start(list, event);
    // Cannot use va_arg(list, type_of_var) here!!!
}
```

The way I call the function might vary depending on my data:

```
write_log(fp, "Memory size :", mem_size);
```

Or

```
write_log(fp, "Username :", username);
```

I have no idea if the 3rd argument is going to be a string or an int or something else.

I could have used `va_arg(list, type_of_var)` but since my data's type varies arbitrarily I cannot use it.

Any idea how can I access the 3rd argument of the function without knowing it's type?

Comment: You cannot. Why do you think functions like printf require a format string?

Comment: Any idea or workarounds for my function then?

Comment: a workaround: define a `struct` with the fields you want, and pass it to the function that writes to the file. That function reads the relevant data from the struct and writes them to your log.

Comment: @Dan Unfortunately, I am confined to C only as of now.

Comment: [This example](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115143/29485) of `_Generic` is the beginning of a C  solution.  The main idea is to use `_Generic` to also pass a value to indicate how to process the ... arguments.

Comment: You could pass a tagged union. The stdio way of passing the type information in the string is also a (not very pretty) possibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no portable standard way to know what the types are.

The first solution that comes to mind is to use the already well-known C idiom of having to pass a format string (e.g. `printf`, `scanf`).

```
void write_log(FILE * fp, char * event, const char* fmt, ...)
{
    va_list list;
    va_start(list, event);

    // process fmt and act accordingly
}
```

If it's going to be only one extra parameter then you can pass an `enum`:

```
enum type {
   integer,
   pointer,
   floating
};

void write_log(FILE * fp, char * event, enum type t, ...)
{
    switch(t)
    {
    case integer: // do stuff with integer
    case pointer: // do stuff with pointer
    }
}
```

If you have access to C11's `_Generic` capabilities, as most modern compilers do, you can have something of the sort:

```
void write_logi(FILE * fp, char * event, int);
void write_logf(FILE * fp, char * event, float);
void write_logfoo(FILE * fp, char * event, struct foo);

#define write_log(file, event, arg) _Generic((arg), \
    int: write_logi,                                \
    float: write_logf,                              \
    struct foo: write_logfoo                        \
)(file, event, arg)
```

Then you can call as:

```
write_log(fp, event, i/*int*/);
write_log(fp, event, f/*float*/);
```

and the appropriate function will be selected.

Comment: UV for `_Generic` which is a portable C11 way to know what the types are, albeit limited to a prior defined set.